# AngularJS service returning a Laravel Blade template

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I have an AngularJS(front-end) and Laravel(back-end) app and I use JWT tokens for authentication. My objective is that when I log in, if the user is an admin, it will use a service that sends a request to the API(laravel backend) that returns a blade template(back-office of admin) that overrides the whole page. Is it possible?

I'm doing this because my Laravel back-end will serve as an API for many front-office apps in the future, and that's why I don't implement the back-office for the admin in AngularJS.

Here is my service in AngularJS:

```
redirectAdmin: function(){
    return $http.get(appConfig.API_URL+'/admin');
},
```

Here is my route in Laravel:

```
Route::get('/admin', function(){
  return view('admin');
});
```

I'm not really sure of what kind of information to put here, so if you need anything let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the thing you want to do is a redirect to be able to change the specific route, to do that just need to add the `$window`like injection and the use the relocation to send the url that you want, for more information here is the link [angular $window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window), remember that $window is a reference of window in javascript so it has all the methods.